# Subtracting column totals with pivot table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I am using the following pivot table to calculate sales per month.

`mon_pay_amount` is used for the the payment amount. I also have a column in the `tbl_orders` table which contains any discount applied this is `mon_order_discount`.

I need to be able to sum the discounts per month and take them away from their respective payment amount monthly totals. In hindsight, discounts should have been recorded in the payment table this would have probably made this easier!

Quite new to `PIVOT` tables and sales reporting, **any one know of any good tutorials**, have been getting by using and modifying examples so far!!

Data Explanation

```
Table Name     ID              FK                  Columns
---------------------------------------------------------------------
tbl_orders     uid_orders                          mon_order_discount
tbl_payment    uid_payment     uid_pay_orderid     mon_pay_amount
```

Data

```
Data:          Jan      Feb      March
Discounts:     10.00    20.00    10.00 
Payments:      200.00   300.00   400.00
```

Results

```
Data:                Jan      Feb      March
Totals-Discount:     190.00   280.000  390.00
```

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT 
      DATENAME(month, dte_pay_paydate) mth,
      mon_pay_amount
  FROM 
      tbl_payment
  INNER JOIN 
      dbo.tbl_orders ON (uid_pay_orderid = uid_orders)
  WHERE 
      bit_pay_paid = 1 
      AND txt_pay_descrip <> 'Credit' 
      AND uid_order_webid = 1
) x
PIVOT
(
  SUM(mon_pay_amount)
  FOR 
     mth IN ([January], [February], [March], [April], [May],
             [June], [July], [August], September, [October], 
             [November], [December])
) p
```

Many thanks

Jason

Comment: It seems that your issue is not with pivot table but with nested query. If nested subquery coock your required data then pivot values will be right. Is this?

Comment: Are you saying carry out the subtraction within the nested subquery? Which will in turn deliver the result to the pivot table.

Comment: @JasonCongerton can you post some sample data and then the desired result?

Comment: yes @JasonCongerton, I'm talking about this. Will be this a solution for you?

Comment: @bluefeet have added data example

Comment: @danihp, if it displays data as I have added to my question then yes that would be the solution

Comment: JasonCongerton, @bluefeet has been posted the query. As you can see discount is take in nested query. Be carefull, a parenthesis is missing after `on` reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the correct amount in your query similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      DATENAME(month, p.dte_pay_paydate) mth,
      p.mon_pay_amount - o.mon_order_discount as Total
  FROM tbl_payment p
  INNER JOIN tbl_orders o 
    ON p.uid_pay_orderid = o.uid_orders
  WHERE bit_pay_paid = 1 
      AND txt_pay_descrip <> 'Credit' 
      AND uid_order_webid = 1
) x
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Total)
  FOR 
     mth IN ([January], [February], [March], [April], [May],
             [June], [July], [August], September, [October], 
             [November], [December])
) p
```

Edit, based on your comments I think the following might work:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT DATENAME(month, p.dte_pay_paydate) mth,
      sum(p.mon_pay_amount) - TotalDiscByMonth Total
  FROM tbl_payment p
  INNER JOIN tbl_orders o1
    on p.uid_pay_orderid = o1.uid_orders
  INNER JOIN
  (
    select sum(mon_order_discount) TotalDiscByMonth, DATENAME(month, dte_order_stamp) mth
    from tbl_orders
    group by DATENAME(month, dte_order_stamp)
  ) o2
    ON DATENAME(month, o1.dte_order_stamp) = o2.mth
  WHERE bit_pay_paid = 1 
      AND txt_pay_descrip <> 'Credit' 
  group by DATENAME(month, p.dte_pay_paydate), TotalDiscByMonth
) x
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Total)
  FOR 
     mth IN ([January], [February], [March], [April], [May],
             [June], [July], [August], September, [October], 
             [November], [December])
) p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4433/17)

Comment: Really strange! It does not appear the query pulls the correct data? For instance in June without removing the discounts I have a total of 166,594.92 when i add the `- o.mon_order_discount` it tells me June is now 39024.47 a difference of 127,570.45 This is far to high, not where near that amount of discount has been applied??

Comment: @JasonCongerton can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8) with your table structures and sample data?  It will be much easier to get the query correct.

Comment: Ok will upload to sql fiddle now. Oops! Have been called into a meeting , will upload to fiddle on my return - thanks for  all you help so far!

Comment: Mmm! in sql fiddle it produces the right result? need to look at data [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01cab/3)

Comment: @JasonCongerton is the discount supposed to be applied to each payment or to just the entire month?  That could be what is causing the problem if you subtract the discount to each payment then it will get multiplied.  So if you have 2 entries for January instead of the discount being applied once it is being applied twice. What is the proper calculation?

Comment: @JasonCongerton please check the query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4433/17) and let me know if that appears to give you the correct result with your full dataset

Comment: yep that works perfectly! Thank you! You are right i need to subtract the total of discounts for that month! Thank you

Comment: @JasonCongerton I copied that query here for future visitors.  Glad it is now working for you.